# SABR model: from calibration to mapping the smile/skew in a graph

Tags: fx, stochastic-volatility, volatility-smile, skewness, sabr

Let's say that I have a calibrated SABR model in FX market (eg for Eurodollar options). So I have estimated values of beta, rho, alpha, and vol of vol. How do I map the calibration in a (strike, vol)-graph. How mathematically challenging would that process be?

Comment: instead of Eurodollar (interest rate futures) you probable mean EUR/USD (FX) options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would simply calculate the prices of various strike options using your parameters, then calculate the black scholes implied vol of each option.  Did I miss the point of your question ?